# App crash after select file using file picker in flutter

Tags: flutter

```
//File Picker
Future<File?> openFilePicker({
  FileType fileType = FileType.custom,
  List<String>? allowedExtensions,
}) async {
  try {
    FilePickerResult? filePickerResult = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
      type: fileType,
      allowMultiple: false,
      allowedExtensions: ['jpg','png','jpeg','pdf'],
    );

    if (filePickerResult != null && filePickerResult.files.isNotEmpty) {
      return File(filePickerResult.files.single.path!);
    } else {
      // User canceled the picker or no file was selected
      return File('');
    }
  } catch (e) {
    // Handle any exceptions that might occur during file picking
    debugPrint('Error picking file: $e');
    return null;
  }
}
```

Error:

```
I/FilePickerUtils(30141): Caching from URI: content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A1000026320
I/FilePickerUtils(30141): Caching from URI: content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A1000026320
D/FilePickerUtils(30141): File loaded and cached at:/data/user/0/com.b2b/cache/file_picker/Screenshot_20231227_132224.jpg
D/FilePickerUtils(30141): File loaded and cached at:/data/user/0/com.b2b/cache/file_picker/Screenshot_20231227_132224.jpg
D/FilePickerDelegate(30141): File path:[com.mr.flutter.plugin.filepicker.FileInfo@392c083]
D/FilePickerDelegate(30141): File path:[com.mr.flutter.plugin.filepicker.FileInfo@4761200]
D/AndroidRuntime(30141): Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime(30141): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(30141): Process: com.b2b, PID: 30141
E/AndroidRuntime(30141): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Reply already submitted
E/AndroidRuntime(30141):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger$Reply.reply(DartMessenger.java:435)
E/AndroidRuntime(30141):    at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler$1.success(MethodChannel.java:263)
E/AndroidRuntime(30141):    at com.mr.flutter.plugin.filepicker.FilePickerPlugin$MethodResultWrapper$1.run(FilePickerPlugin.java:214)
E/AndroidRuntime(30141):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
E/AndroidRuntime(30141):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(30141):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:257)
E/AndroidRuntime(30141):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8183)
E/AndroidRuntime(30141):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(30141):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:626)
E/AndroidRuntime(30141):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1015)
W/FirebaseCrashlytics(30141): Unable to read App Quality Sessions session id.
I/Process (30141): Sending signal. PID: 30141 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Please share more details and Make sure you have given necessary permissions for pick file.

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> I have given this permissions .
here I'.m using file picker await openFilePicker(
                                fileType: FileType.custom,
                                allowedExtensions: fileFormatList,
                              ).then(
                                (pickedFile) async {}

Comment: Crash doesn't come from permission, because based on the logs, picture already loaded and cache. Try to use [image_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker) plugin. I use it and there isn't problem.